# Bootstrap form validation and submit using bootstrap validator

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap popup modal form in my website as contact form.I did form validation using bootstrap form validation.Now i want to submit form and display success or error message in the same modal form.

[image]

I did the validation using

```
<script src="js/bootstrapValidator.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('#contest-form').bootstrapValidator();
</script>
```

Comment: I think the header should say "Contact form" instead of "Contest form"

Comment: Ajax is the solution you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use Ajax. The JavaScript is as follows (**Note**: This utilises an element with an ID of `result` to display the result):

```
$('body').on('success.form.bv', '#form', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'form-submission.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: formData,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#result').html(result);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            # error handling here
        }
    })

});
```

And a rough example of the PHP:

```
// do whatever with the form - you have access to $_POST
$form_submitted = false // or true, depending on your PHP

if ($form_submitted) {

    echo '<div class="alert animated fadeIn alert-dismissable alert-success"><strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.</div>';

} else {

    echo '<div class="alert animated fadeIn alert-dismissable alert-danger"><strong>Error!</strong> There was an error submitting the form.</div>';

}
```

Comment: Hi thnx..i tried but i want to call the ajax function only after validation is currect...how can i do that...

Comment: @PHPCoder Ah sorry - I have edited my answer. Change `submit` to `success.form.bv` (the first line in my example above)